# Pig Installation Verication failed

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to install pig 0.13 in ubuntu

I downloaded the pig-0.13.0.tar.gz and installed in $HOME path

After that I edit .bashrc file with below export commands

Please look at my .bashrc file

```
export HADOOP_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-1.2.1
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HOME/hadoop-1.2.1/conf
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-1.2.1/conf
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-1.2.1
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-1.2.1
###################JAVA############################
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i36

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/hadoop-1.2.1/bin

########################PIG#######################
export PIG_HOME=/home/user/pig-0.13.0
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
```

But when i try to test whether pig is launced correctly or not.. it is not activated..

I reboot my machine and applied source .bashrc as well but nothing helped

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ls
Desktop    examples.desktop     Music       pig-0.13.0.tar.gz  Templates
Documents  hadoop-1.2.1         Pictures    Public             Videos
Downloads  hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz  pig-0.13.0  surender
user@ubuntu:~$ hadoop version
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Hadoop 1.2.1
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches  /branch-1.2 -r 1503152
Compiled by mattf on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
From source with checksum 6923c86528809c4e7e6f493b6b413a9a
This command was run using /home/user/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
user@ubuntu:~$ pig -help
pig: invalid option -- 'h'
usage: pig
user@ubuntu:~$
```

my $HOME is /home/user

Could somebody help me on this?

Comment: Can you do a `ls -l` in the home directory of `user` and add the result to this question?

Comment: user@ubuntu:~$ pwd
/home/user
user@ubuntu:~$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 user user     8445 Apr 28  2012 examples.desktop
drwxr-xr-x 16 user user     4096 Aug  8 07:52 hadoop-1.2.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 63851630 Aug  7 14:13 hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 15 user user     4096 Aug 10 11:51 pig-0.12.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 59445085 Aug  9 11:40 pig-0.12.1.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 97256865 Aug  8 08:48 pig-0.13.0.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user     4096 Apr 28  2012 Public

Comment: I tried with pig 0.12 also.. Still same error. but if I try to go inside pig installation directory and then if I type bin/pig then it works.. but I don't  want to do that way

Comment: Why didn't you use $HOME/pig-0.13.0 when you are exporting PIG_HOME?. Try it and let me know if it works.